# How can I match a numerical sequence of any length via regex?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I need a regex to match a number of any length followed by a `.html`.

For example sample matched strings would be:

4.html
32.html
46352.html

So basically any number followed by `.html`.

Comment: Tell us please what have you done so far and where exactly you have difficulties.

Comment: I am using regex with coldfusion. I can match the sequence of numbers, but can't match the `.html`. This is what I have and correctly matches the numbers:

REFind("\d+", "My page is 123.html! hey 7689")

I've been trying this:

REFind("\d+/^.html$/", "ColdFusion 123.html! hey 7689")

But does not match `123.html`

Comment: @paddyc -  Could you move that code snippet into the question so it's more visible, then delete the comment?

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log("ColdFusion 123.html! hey 7689".match(/\d+\.html/)[0])
```

Or in your case: `REFind("\d+\.html", "ColdFusion 123.html! hey 7689")`

`^` in "\d+/^.html$/" does not escape `.`. To escape `.` you need to use `\`. Also `$` means "the end of string" and `123.html` is not in the end. And I don't know what `/` around `^.html$` mean in *ColdFusion*, but they surely look strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

If regex is optional, you can do this with ColdFusion functions:

```
if (
listlen(yourstring, '.') == 2 
&&
listlast(yourstring, '.') == 'html'
&&
isnumeric(listfirst(yourstring, '.')) == true
)
code for match
else
code for no match
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 REFindNoCase("\d+\.html", str, 1, 1);
```

That will get you at least one number followed by the literal string "." followed by the literal string "html".

If you want it to be case sensitive, then just use the REFind() version:

```
 REFind("\d+\.html", str, 1, 1);
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

If your are searching a text for multiple matches you should/could use rematch or rematchnocase (case insensitive) like this:

```
<Cfdump var="#rematch("\d+\.html", "Test string 123.html! testing a little mor bla.html. Stil testing 1.html")#">
```

You can view an online example here:
https://trycf.com/gist/5426f17eda973b3819efefc04e8fd311/lucee5?theme=monokai